# C# TreeView how can I get the TreeNode at an index position?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Every `TreeNode` in `TreeView` has an unique index.

I can't find a method in the C# `TreeView` control to get the node at a given index position (`GetNodeAt()` just gives the node at a drawing point).

**Is there way to get the TreeNode when I know only it's index?**

**Edit**

```
myTreeView.SelectedNode.Index = <wanted index>
```

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37009288/1574221) does not work. The property is read only.

**Edit2**

**What do I need that for:** To avoid recursive searching in verly large TreeViews I would like to run

```
for(int i = startPosition; i < treeView.GetNodeCount(); i++)
```

check the node, get the index and then select the found node using the index.

Comment: Your statement does not appear to be true.  Each `TreeNode` has an `Index` property that is unique to the `Nodes` collection it belongs to.  But `TreeView`s aren't flat, so a `TreeNode` does not necessarily belong to the topmost `Nodes` collection and therefore its `Index` is not unique to the entire `TreeView`.

Comment: I don't understand why this questions got's down voted two times and got close votes. I had the problem to get the TreeNode at an index. So I searched for `c# treeview get node at index`, `c# treeview get child at index` and others more. All I found was GetNodeAt() which doesn't fit my needs. Finally I asked here. Ok - most C# programmers at Stackoverlfow are better than I am and I don't understand the C# concept completely. But the requirement for asking here should not be the level of knowledge, but the effort in investigation before asking and then a well formulated question. Am I wrong?

Comment: @boboes, yes, if I understand the documentation correctly.

Comment: @MethodMan `SelectedNode.Level`= "The zero-based depth of the tree node in the TreeView control.". It is read only (from MSDN). How does it answer my question `how can I get the TreeNode at an index?`

Comment: typo it should be `TreeView.SelectedNode.Index`

Comment: @MethodMan `TreeView.SelectedNode.Index` Is also a read only property. How does it answer my question?

Comment: @adv12: wrote a little demo to clarify it and added it to the question

Comment: @boboes, `TreeView` controls are often used to hold a hierarchical "tree" of nodes, not just a flat list.  In your demo code, you never add nodes below other nodes, so you really just have a flat list.  Within that top-level `Nodes` list, each node has a unique index.  If you were to add nodes below the top level, the `Index` property would not be unique over the whole `TreeView`.  This is why there is no `GetNodeAtIndex()` method:  in the general case, it's nonsense.  If you know your `TreeView` will always be a flat list, you can get the node at an index with `myTreeView.Nodes[index]`.

Comment: @adv12 Thats conclusive. I would accept this as an answer.

Comment: @adv12 Ok, this seems to be a missunderstanding. The TreeView is not flat. I made an edit in the question.

Comment: @boboes, the hypothetical `for` loop you edited into your question will not work.  You must iterate over each `Nodes` list separately.  There is no built-in mapping between your loop counter variable and particular nodes within a large tree.  Time to give up and write a recursive function (which is really no slower than a linear search in this situation anyway).  If you really have so many nodes that a recursive search is too slow, you probably have enough to bog down the UI and should be looking at other UI approaches.

Comment: @adv12 Now I know that it won't work. I just edited the question to explain why I've been asking that. My problem isn't the speed but the fact, that I need a search function which starts at the current selected node, supports both directions and needs to consider wrap arounds. This is easier to implement with a linar list. Now it is implemented as recursive search.: It works and is fast enougt. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption `"Every TreeNode in TreeView has an unique index."` is **wrong**.  It's only correct for a node at a certain level.

**What to do to get the "TreeNode at an index position"?**

I need to save all index positions from the root to my wanted node. With this information I can find my saved node later.

Answer (score 1):

There is a perfect example of how to do this on MSDN.

`TreeView.SelectedNode.Index`

[MSDN: TreeNode.Index Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.index%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[MSDN: TreeView Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT:**
I hadn't read the question fully. The information you need for your problem is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203975/move-node-in-tree-up-or-down)

Comment: From the definition in: `public class TreeNode : MarshalByRefObject, ICloneable, ISerializable` I find: `public int Index { get; }`. That means that the index is **read only** and cannot be assigned. How does this answer my question?

Comment: See this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203975/move-node-in-tree-up-or-down)

Comment: The index in a TreeView is not unique over all nodes. Its only unique for a single level. So the answer to my question is: It doesn't work when the TreeView has multiple levels.