# C# TreeView selected node loosing Focus after moving that node

Tags: c#

I am working with Windows Form project. I am using VS2013 and .net version is 4.5. i do not have very high knowledge in .Net.

I want to up down any node of my tree view which was possible from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/2204091/14326209

Here is the code

```
/// <summary>
        /// Move Selected Node Up in TreeNode Collection
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="node"></param>
        public static void MoveUp(this TreeNode node)
        {
            TreeNode parent = node.Parent;
            TreeView view = node.TreeView;

            if (parent != null)
            {
                int index = parent.Nodes.IndexOf(node);
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    parent.Nodes.RemoveAt(index);
                    parent.Nodes.Insert(index - 1, node);
                    node.Text = node.Text;
                }
            }
            else if (node.TreeView.Nodes.Contains(node)) //root node
            {
                int index = view.Nodes.IndexOf(node);
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    view.Nodes.RemoveAt(index);
                    view.Nodes.Insert(index - 1, node);
                    node.Text = node.Text;
                }
            }

            //view.Focus();
            //view.SelectedNode = node;
            //node.EnsureVisible();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Move Selected Node Down in TreeNode Collection
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="node"></param>
        public static void MoveDown(this TreeNode node)
        {
            TreeNode parent = node.Parent;
            TreeView view = node.TreeView;

            if (parent != null)
            {
                int index = parent.Nodes.IndexOf(node);
                if (index < parent.Nodes.Count - 1)
                {
                    parent.Nodes.RemoveAt(index);
                    parent.Nodes.Insert(index + 1, node);
                    node.Text = node.Text;
                }
            }
            else if (view != null && view.Nodes.Contains(node)) //root node
            {
                int index = view.Nodes.IndexOf(node);
                if (index < view.Nodes.Count - 1)
                {
                    view.Nodes.RemoveAt(index);
                    view.Nodes.Insert(index + 1, node);
                    node.Text = node.Text;
                }
            }
            //view.Focus();
            //view.SelectedNode = node;
            //node.EnsureVisible();

        }

private void tvCsmTuner_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                tvCsmTuner.SelectedNode.MoveUp();
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                tvCsmTuner.SelectedNode.MoveDown();
            }

            label3.Focus();
        }
```

when i call `Node.MoveDown() and Node.MoveUp()` then Node is getting perfectly moving but selection from Selected node going to different node after node moved. i want selection should persist on selected node after moving the Node.

So please guide me what changes need to add in the above code as a result selection on selected node should not go to any node.

I tried this to persist node selection but did not work.

```
view.SelectedNode = node;
```

Looking for suggestion. thanks

Comment: `TreeView.HideSelection = false;`

Comment: if i set HideSelection = false then what will happen ?

Comment: A selected `TreeNode` remains _visually_ selected when the control loses the focus.

Comment: ok i will set this `TreeView.HideSelection = false` and let u know the result. thanks